# How to automate an existing publisher file (.pub) using win32com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com, pywinauto

Is there any way I can automate my publisher file. I have a publisher template and I want to edit few parts of the file with new data every time. And data is in an excel file. Basically I want to edit excel file with the publisher template to get the required output everytime I feed new excel. And then create a pdf after all the changes made to the .pub file. Can anyone tell me if i can do it with **win32com** or **pywin32** or **pywinauto** ? Or any other methods?

Comment: You automate applications, not files. Assuming you use Microsoft Publisher is installed, you can easily automate it with COM using the same API that's used by VBA macros. You can even record a macro and inspect the generated code and replicate the steps in any language you want. It doesn't really matter which COM library you use in Python as long as it works

Comment: Okay thanks @PanagiotisKanavos . It automates applications. I am trying to use win32com and I have written the open command win32com.client.DispatchEx("Publisher.Application").open(pub_file) and it showed no error that means it opened but whenever I try to do win32com.client.DispatchEx("Publisher.Application").visible=1 it throws an error. And I currently have no idea how to link the excel data with the publisher using this.

Comment: Record a macro in Publisher while you do the steps you want and check that code. You'll have to make the same calls to read the Excel data. You don't need to make the application visible to work with it

Comment: I'm not nitpicking. You have to search Publisher's COM API docs to find how it imports data, including Excel data. Nobody remembers that stuff. Why not have Publisher generate that code for you by recording a macro?

Comment: Do you have any basic commands that I can look into? I don't really understand what you're saying I'm quite new to this library. And publisher is quite intricate to automate in comparing with Excel.

Comment: you try this? https://win32com.goermezer.de/microsoft/ms-office/converting-from-microsoft-office-publisher-to-postscript.html